# In typescript, how to return sub class instance in a static function in base class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here is my code:

```js
class BaseElement {
    public static create<T extends typeof BaseElement>(this: T ): InstanceType<T> {
        this.createHelper();
        const r = new this();
        return r;
    }
    public static createHelper() {
        // implementation omitted.
    }
}
```

I hope the static `create` function will return a instance of current type(the same with `this`).

But it doesn't work:

```
Type 'BaseElement' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<T>'.
```

Please note that `create` depends on another static function (like `createHelper` for example), so I can't use this signature

```
create<T extends BaseElement>(this: new () => T): T
```

How can I fix the type annotation of above code? Thanks in advance.

-------------update----------------

Looks it is not possible now (except the work around in accepted answer). There is a issue tracking it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863)

Comment: Why are you returning `InstanceType` if you want to return an instance?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, I am new to typescript.  If not , how can I annotate the return type?

Comment: So what do you want to pass as a parameter to the `create()` function? An instance? Or a type?

Comment: ```create``` should be a static function of type BaseElement.  In real code, it has other parameters, and acts like a constructor.

Comment: `InstanceType` is a conditional type, and the compiler doesn't do a good job understanding assignability to conditional types depending on unspecified type parameters. Consider the signature `create<T extends BaseElement>(this: new () => T): T` instead.

Comment: @jcalz, thank you for your help. Actually I tried. In real code, I need to access other static function of ```BaseElement``` in ```create```. Your solution doesn't work in this case. I will refine the question.

Comment: How does `this.createHelper()` affect anything? Are you storing some kind of static state and expecting it to carry into the sub-class?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger: It will complains: ``` Property 'createHelper' does not exist on type 'new () => T'.```

Comment: That's because you are using `this` as the parameter name, `this` is a reserved keyword. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid mixing generic type parameters and conditional types unless you are prepared to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) inside the method implementations: the compiler isn't really able to verify that a value is assignable to a deferred conditional type (one depending on some generic type parameter that isn't specified yet).  If you really want to do it, you can:

```
class BaseElementAsssert {
    public static create<T extends typeof BaseElementAsssert>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {
        this.createHelper();
        const r = new this();
        return r as InstanceType<T>; // assert here
    }
    public static createHelper() {
        // implementation omitted.
    }
}
```

It's fine to do that, as long as you're willing to take responsibility for verifying the types are what you assert them to be.  For example, you can change the `r` assignment to `const r = new BaseElementAsssert();` and the compiler won't complain.  When you assert things to the compiler, it's easier to lie to it.  So be careful.

---

In this case I would probably rewrite the code so that the generic type is the intended instance type.  If you need access to both the static properties of `BaseElement`'s constructor *and* have the compiler infer the instance type, you could use an [intersection type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
class BaseElement {
    public static create<T extends BaseElement>(this: typeof BaseElement & (new () => T)) {
        this.createHelper();
        const r = new this();
        return r;
    }
    public static createHelper() {
        console.log("called createHelper on " + this.name);
    }
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMCiIEFsEDsAuBBKECATttAN4CwAUNLdAA4CuARiAJbDQTZjYfTAiCXggA8AFWgIAHtiwATGNgCe9BAHsAZnEQp0WPAWLYAfAApsACzYQAXNHEBKewElM3MJmAJxqseJNyajoQ6CsbADpBYTkACQQQNSIzRwBuYNDaYHV3UiJoAF5oTAQAdzDrCBT0mkzoIWxGIkx66EhoNw8vHz8JE1ToAHpBtqhjaEtiBAzaAF8ZhhZ2Tg8+TmiReMTiFKDazOHoNjR6VAwcXjYc6HU0Nmw5eQiF+apX6GpQSBh4Qj1z0iUfaLVj8Vb8DZyCRSWQKH66M4GczhOxhPxaHR-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)